# Double encoding when retrieving data saved to blob in MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, blob

I have a Nested python list containing data such as the one shown longlist.
I have the code that makes this list into a json like string then i encode it in order to feed it to the base64.b64encoder and subsequently save it to my mysql DB as a blob with some other data. when I try to retrieve the data and convert it back to a list I run into the issue of what I can only describe as double encoding.

```
longlist = [
    [1, 2,'thisisdhdh'],
    [1,2,'thlsldfsdf'],
    [2,0,'sdlfjldksjflksdj']
] 

string1 = json.dumps(longlist)

encod1 = string1.encode('ascii')

encodedlist = base64.b64encode(encod1)

cur.execute('INSERT INTO conversations (convoblob) VALUES ("%s")' % (encodedlist))

code above to save the encoded list to the DB

code below to retrieve the data

cur.execute('SELECT convoblob FROM conversations WHERE id IN (327) ')
item = cur.fetchone()

x = items[0]
```

1.output type class bytes
b"b'W1sxLCAyLCAidGhpc2lzZGhkaCJdLCBbMSwgMiwgInRobHNsZGZzZGYiXSwgWzIsIDAsICJzZGxmamxka3N1.qZmxrc2RqIl1d'"

```
       x = items[0].decode('ascii')
```

1.output type class 'str' 1.b'W1sxLCAyLCAidGhpc2lzZGhkaCJdLCBbMSwgMiwgInRobHNsZGZzZGYiXSwgWzIsIDAsICJzZGxmamxka3NqZ1.mxrc2RqIl1d'

as you can see decoding it once turns it into a string that I cant run a decoder on.

Not saving the data to the DB will decode just fine, for some reason once the data goes to the database it comes back with the (b")beginning of sting and (") at the end

my DB default charset is utf8mb4

I did find a work around which is to decode the data pulled from the database, and chop of the bits on the end of the string that identify it as a byte like string and then to encod the string back and then decod it with base64.b64decode

```
cur.execute('SELECT convoblob FROM conversations WHERE id IN (327) ')
item = cur.fetchone()
decoded = item[0].decode('ascii')
y = len(decoded) - 1
newString = decoded[2:y]
this = newString.encode('ascii')
man = base64.b64decode(this).decode('ascii')
ohyeah = json.loads(man)
print(ohyeah[1])
```

output is b'W1sxLCAyLCAidGhpc2lzZGhkaCJdLCBbMSwgMiwgInRobHNsZGZzZGYiXSwgWzIsIDAsICJzZGxmamxka3NqZmxrc2RqIl1d'

[1, 2, 'thlsldfsdf']

Comment: Why are you going through all this rigmarole? Convert your list to a JSON string as you have done above, then save that in your database. Then there's only one step to recreate your list.

Comment: because the data is a python nested list that i want to preserve. someone sugested encoding it in base 64 so as to not have issues with injection from sql, which i dont know what that is but it sounds scary .

Comment: The way to defend against SQL injection is not to apply some ad hoc encoding, but to use prepared statements. Note the line `conn.execute('INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (?)', [encodedlist])` in Grismar's answer: that's a prepared statement and is immune to SQL injection attacks. Use your JSON-encoded list there, and you can just decode the JSON when you retrieve it.

Comment: Get rid of the base64 (coming and going); change the "%s" to binding.

Comment: thanks for that. i didn't know what injection meant honestly. i though it was a injection by the database that would add some notation to the data for performance reasons. So you are saying that the injection refers to malicious actor injecting some code that would f up my database. ok, thats wouldn't be anything to worry about since this is not a db open to the internet. I already have about 1k record in the db using what i have now. and will be shooting to build about 50k or more records. is there may be a memory advantage to continue encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

```
import sqlite3
import json
import base64

longlist = [
    [1, 2,'thisisdhdh'],
    [1,2,'thlsldfsdf'],
    [2,0,'sdlfjldksjflksdj']
] 

# you create a string
# '[[1, 2, "thisisdhdh"], [1, 2, "thlsldfsdf"], [2, 0, "sdlfjldksjflksdj"]]'
string1 = json.dumps(longlist)

# you create a bytes object from the string, happens to be encoded as ascii
# b'[[1, 2, "thisisdhdh"], [1, 2, "thlsldfsdf"], [2, 0, "sdlfjldksjflksdj"]]'
encod1 = string1.encode('ascii')

# you create a base-64 encoding of that object, still bytes
# b'W1sxLCAyLCAidGhpc2lzZGhkaCJdLCBbMSwgMiwgInRobHNsZGZzZGYiXSwgWzIsIDAsICJzZGxmamxka3NqZmxrc2RqIl1d'
encodedlist = base64.b64encode(encod1)

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conversations')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE conversations (convoblob BLOB)')
# you format that bytes object into a string (casting it to a string) <<< your problem
conn.execute('INSERT INTO conversations VALUES ("%s")' % (encodedlist))

cur = conn.execute('SELECT convoblob FROM conversations')
item = cur.fetchone()

# no surprise about the mangled string here, since it was cast back into a string first
# "b'W1sxLCAyLCAidGhpc2lzZGhkaCJdLCBbMSwgMiwgInRobHNsZGZzZGYiXSwgWzIsIDAsICJzZGxmamxka3NqZmxrc2RqIl1d'"
print(item[0])

# Let's try again
conn.close()
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conversations')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE conversations (convoblob BLOB)')
# now passing the bytes directly to the database, as bytes, into a blob
conn.execute('INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (?)', [encodedlist])

cur = conn.execute('SELECT convoblob FROM conversations')
item = cur.fetchone()

# This works:
my_list = json.loads(base64.b64decode(item[0]))
print(my_list)
```

I know you use MySQL, but it works the same for SQLite (and has the same problem), so I'm sure this is your issue and `sqlite3` works on any standard Python installation.

So, in short: by formatting a `bytes` object into a string using %-formatting, you create the `"b'data'"` object causing you trouble. That can be avoided by passing the `bytes` itself to the SQL engine and having it pass it to the query using a query parameter, which is a better way to go about it anyway to avoid SQL injection.